# applyInPandas() aggregation runs slowly on big delta table

Tags: performance, optimization, pyspark, aggregation, delta-live-tables

I'm trying to create a gold table notebook in Databricks, however it would take 9 days to fully reprocess the historical data (43GB, 35k parquet files). I tried scaling up the cluster but it doesn't go above 5000 records/second. The bottleneck seems to be the `applyInPandas()` function. I'm wondering if I could replace pandas with anything else to make the gold notebook execute faster.

Silver table has 60 columns (`read_id`, `reader_id`, `tracker_timestamp`, `event_type`, `ebook_id`, `page_id`, `agent_ip`, `agent_device_type`, ...). Each row of data represents read event of an ebook. E.g 'page turn', 'click on image', 'click on link',... All of the events that have occurred in the single session have the same `read.id`. In the gold table I'm trying to group those events in sessions and calculate the number of times each event has occurred in the single session. So instead of 100+ rows of data for a read session in silver table I would end up just with a single aggregated row in gold table.

Input is the silver delta table:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

input = (spark
         .readStream
         .format("delta")
         .option("withEventTimeOrder", "true")
         .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 100)
         .load(f"path_to_silver_bucket")
        )
```

I use `withWatermark` and `session_window` functions to ensure I end up grouping all of the events from the single read session. (read session automatically ends 30 minutes after the last reader activity)

`group = input.withWatermark("tracker_timestamp", "10 minutes").groupBy("read_id", F.session_window(input.tracker_timestamp, "30 minutes"))`

In the next step I use the `applyInPandas` function like so:
`sessions = group.applyInPandas(processing_function, schema=processing_function_output_schema)`

Definition of the `processing_function` used in `applyInPandas`:

```py
def processing_function(df):
    surf_time_ms = df.query('event_type == "surf"')['duration'].sum()
    immerse_time_ms = df.query('event_type == "immersion"')['duration'].sum()
    min_timestamp = df['tracker_timestamp'].min()
    max_timestamp = df['tracker_timestamp'].max()
    shares = len(df.query('event_type == "share"'))
    leads = len(df.query('event_type == "lead_store"'))
    is_read = len(df.query('event_type == "surf"')) > 0
    distinct_pages = df['page_id'].nunique()

    data = {
        "read_id": df['read_id'].values[0],
        "surf_time_ms": surf_time_ms,
        "immerse_time_ms": immerse_time_ms,
        "min_timestamp": min_timestamp,
        "max_timestamp": max_timestamp,
        "shares": shares,
        "leads": leads,
        "is_read": is_read,
        "number_of_events": len(df),
        "distinct_pages": distinct_pages
    }
    
    for field in not_calculated_string_fields:
      data[field] = df[field].values[0]
    
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['read_id'])
    
    for x in all_events:
        new_df[f"count_{x}"] = df.query(f"type == '{x}'").count()
            
    for x in duration_events:
        duration = df.query(f"event_type == '{x}'")['duration']
        duration_sum = duration.sum()
        new_df[f"duration_{x}_ms"] = duration_sum
        if duration_sum > 0:
            new_df[f"mean_duration_{x}_ms"] = duration.mean()
        else:
            new_df[f"mean_duration_{x}_ms"] = 0

    return new_df
```

And finally, I'm writing the calculated row to the gold table like so:

```py
for_partitioning = (sessions
      .withColumn("tenant", F.col("story_tenant"))
      .withColumn("year", F.year(F.col("min_timestamp")))
      .withColumn("month", F.month(F.col("min_timestamp"))))

checkpoint_path = "checkpoint-path"
gold_path = f"gold-bucket"
(for_partitioning
      .writeStream
      .format('delta')
      .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'tenant')
      .option("mergeSchema", "true")
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
      .outputMode("append")
      .start(gold_path))
```

Can anybody think of a more efficient way to do a UDF in PySpark than `applyInPandas` for the above example? I simply cannot afford to wait 9 days to reprocess 43GB of data...

I've tried playing around with different input and output options (e.g. `.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 100)`) but the real problem seems to be `applyInPandas`.

Comment: I think the main issue is that you're not using pandas correctly - you're using native Python functions in place of better placed vectorised solutions written for the pandas API. this is a hard question to answer - I think you need to create a [mcve] with your input data and what you expect your output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite your `processing_function` into native Spark if you really wanted.

`"read_id": df['read_id'].values[0]`

```py
F.first('read_id').alias('read_id')
```

`"surf_time_ms": df.query('event_type == "surf"')['duration'].sum()`

```py
F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'surf', F.col('duration'))).alias('surf_time_ms')
```

`"immerse_time_ms": df.query('event_type == "immersion"')['duration'].sum()`

```py
F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'immersion', F.col('duration'))).alias('immerse_time_ms')
```

`"min_timestamp": df['tracker_timestamp'].min()`

```py
F.min('tracker_timestamp').alias('min_timestamp')
```

`"max_timestamp": df['tracker_timestamp'].max()`

```py
F.max('tracker_timestamp').alias('max_timestamp')
```

`"shares": len(df.query('event_type == "share"'))`

```py
F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'share', F.lit(1))).alias('shares')
```

`"leads": len(df.query('event_type == "lead_store"'))`

```py
F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'lead_store', F.lit(1))).alias('leads')
```

`"is_read": len(df.query('event_type == "surf"')) > 0`

```py
(F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'surf', F.lit(1))) > 0).alias('is_read')
```

`"number_of_events": len(df)`

```py
F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('number_of_events')
```

`"distinct_pages": df['page_id'].nunique()`

```py
F.countDistinct('page_id').alias('distinct_pages')
```

`for field in not_calculated_string_fields:`
    `data[field] = df[field].values[0]`

```py
*[F.first(field).alias(field) for field in not_calculated_string_fields]
```

`for x in all_events:`                                         
    `new_df[f"count_{x}"] = df.query(f"type == '{x}'").count()`

*The above can probably be skipped? As far as my tests go, new columns get NaN values, because `.count()` returns a Series object instead of one simple value.*

`for x in duration_events:`                                  
    `duration = df.query(f"event_type == '{x}'")['duration']`
    `duration_sum = duration.sum()`                          
    `new_df[f"duration_{x}_ms"] = duration_sum`              
    `if duration_sum > 0:`                                   
        `new_df[f"mean_duration_{x}_ms"] = duration.mean()`  
    `else:`                                                  
        `new_df[f"mean_duration_{x}_ms"] = 0`

```py
*[F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == x, F.col('duration'))).alias(f"duration_{x}_ms") for x in duration_events]
*[F.mean(F.when(F.col('event_type') == x, F.col('duration'))).alias(f"mean_duration_{x}_ms") for x in duration_events]
```

---

So, instead of

```py
def processing_function(df):
    ...
    ...

sessions = group.applyInPandas(processing_function, schema=processing_function_output_schema)
```

you could use efficient native Spark:

```py
sessions = group.agg(
    F.first('read_id').alias('read_id'),
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'surf', F.col('duration'))).alias('surf_time_ms'),
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'immersion', F.col('duration'))).alias('immerse_time_ms'),
    F.min('tracker_timestamp').alias('min_timestamp'),
    F.max('tracker_timestamp').alias('max_timestamp'),
    F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'share', F.lit(1))).alias('shares'),
    F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'lead_store', F.lit(1))).alias('leads'),
    (F.count(F.when(F.col('event_type') == 'surf', F.lit(1))) > 0).alias('is_read'),
    F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('number_of_events'),
    F.countDistinct('page_id').alias('distinct_pages'),
    *[F.first(field).alias(field) for field in not_calculated_string_fields],
    # skipped count_{x} 
    *[F.sum(F.when(F.col('event_type') == x, F.col('duration'))).alias(f"duration_{x}_ms") for x in duration_events],
    *[F.mean(F.when(F.col('event_type') == x, F.col('duration'))).alias(f"mean_duration_{x}_ms") for x in duration_events],
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you truly are a wizard!! The processing time just went down from 9 days to 2 hours.